# Getting parameters from Zend rest controllers processing it and returning data to the controllers

Tags: api, zend-framework, rest, frameworks, controllers

I am working on a restful zend-API frame work. The problem is, when a request is posted, i don't have the concept of how to get the data from the controllers into a separate class for processing and returning the processed output back to the controller. 
i.e the best way to implement the putAction function below

```
public function putAction()
    {     
        $resource = $this->_getParam('resource');
        $this->view->resource = $resource;
        //$requests = $this->getRequest();

        switch (true) {
            case (strstr($resource, 'account')):
               $response = $this -> do_post_request($requests);
               $resource = "You are accessing account";
                break;
            case (strstr($resource, 'property')):
                           $response = $this -> do_post_request($requests);
               $resource = "You are accessing  property";
                break;
        case (strstr($resource, 'autos')):
                           $response = $this -> do_post_request($requests);
               $resource = "You are accessing  autos";
                break;
            default:
                 $resource = "The specified resource is not available please check the api manual for available resources";
                break;
        }
        $this->view->message = $response;
        $this->_response->ok(); 
    }
```

where the response is collected after being processed by other functions in other classes.
 If i was to use the: $response = $this -> do_post_request($requests); 
how will the structure of the other classes be for them to process the request and produce the response

Answer (score 3):

Standard practice is to have a separate controller for each resource.  Let's say you have a module called api with the namespace 'Api_' that you've set up in your application.ini file like so:

```
autoloadernamespaces = "Api_"
```

Then, you should have 3 controllers like the following in your api module folder:

```
class Api_AccountController extends Zend_Rest_Controller {
    public function init()
    {
    }
    public function getAction()
    {
    }
    public function postAction()
    {
    }
    public function putAction()
    {
    }
    public function deleteAction()
    {
    }
}
```

The others are obviously Api_AutoController, Api_PropertyController.  Then, you have to tell Zend which module to use for Rest requests.  In your application.ini file:

```
routes.api.type = Zend_Rest_Route
routes.api.defaults.module = api
routes.api.defaults.controller = api
routes.api.api = auto,account,property
```

Zend will now automagically respond to requests like GET http://yourapplication.com/auto/:id
where :id is a unique identifier for an auto.  This isn't Rails, so you are of course responsible for writing the code in Api_AutoContoller's getAction() method to query the database and return information about the auto of id :id, etc.  If you need to pass additional parameters to one of the routes, you can do one of the following:

(1) Make the id param explicit:
[ApplicationURL]/auto/id/123/color/blue
(2) Include the other params in the request body, or appended to the URL:
[ApplicationURL]/auto/123?color=blue

NOTE: you don't have to shove all this into a separate module.  If your application is small and simple, using a separate module for the Api might not make sense.  But this is a setup I've used with success for projects at work.